# What is meant by a "change in volume of a system"?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, work, vacuum, ideal-gas

I keep getting confused when my professor talks about the change in volume of a system. Sometimes it seems as though he's talking about the volume of the gas and at other times he might be talking about the volume of the actual container. Which is the correct interpretation?

Also, how would the answer apply to the free expansion of a gas into a vacuum? I'm told that no work is being done on the system nor is there work being done by the system, but $P\mathrm dv>0$. This would tell me that what we mean by "change in volume of a system" means the gas, not the container...

Comment: Sometimes it is more convenient to take the system as the gas, and other times it is more convenient to take the system as the container.

Answer (score 2):

> What is meant by a “change in volume of a system”?

"Change in volume of a system" means "change in volume of a system", not anything else. System is a hypothetical concept. There is no specified system before we define it. We ourselves choose and define system. When someone talks about a system defined by himself/herself, he/she talks about that system not any other system. So, when your teacher talks about the volume of the gas, he/she has chosen the gas inside the container as system. When your teacher talks about the volume of the actual container, he/she certainly has chosen whole of the container as system.

---

**About free expansion:**

We know that work is defined by $$\delta w=P\mathrm dv$$
But, what is the $P$?

$P$ is the pressure that **resists against** the system boundary movement not pressure of the system itself. In free expansion, there is no pressure that prevents the boundary movement. So, although $\mathrm dv\neq0$; since $P=0$ work done by gas will be zero ($\delta w=P\mathrm dv=0$).